# OneSignal setNotificationReceivedHandler can't set adapter

Tags: android, push-notification, chat, onesignal

I try to make chat app with OneSignal. And i want listview to set adapter when notification coming. If i use `setNotificationOpenedHandler` it's work, but i should click prompt notification to make listview set the adapter. The problem is , i no want click the prompt/notification to set adapter listview, so i use `setNotificationReceivedHandler` , but not work, not change anything.

This for Open Handler (**work**)

```
  OneSignal.startInit(this)
.setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dt = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("a", "testing 2");
                        dt.add(map);
                        ChatMessageAdapter adap = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, dt);
                        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChat);
                        listView.setAdapter(adap);
                    }
                })
                .init();
```

And this for receive Handler (**not work**)

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
.setNotificationReceivedHandler(new OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dt = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("a", "testing 1");
                        dt.add(map);
                        ChatMessageAdapter adap = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, dt);
                        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewChat);
                        listView.setAdapter(adap);
                    }
                })
                .init();
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce any issues with `notificationReceived` not firing. Make sure you calling `OneSIgnal.startInit(..)` from the `onCreate` of your Application class instead of an Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Download the latest [OneSignal Android SDK](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases).
2. Use this code in application code:

   ```
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().build());
   StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().build());

      OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
      OneSignal.startInit(this)
     .autoPromptLocation(true)
     .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
     .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
     .init();
   ```
3. And this is your **ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler**:

   ```
   public class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements NotificationReceivedHandler {

   /**
   * Callback to implement in your app to handle when a notification is
   * received while your app running in the foreground or background.
   *
   * Use a NotificationExtenderService instead to receive an event even when
   * your app is closed (not 'forced stopped') or to override notification
   * properties.
   *
   * @param notification
   *            Contains information about the notification received.
   */
   @Override
   public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
   Log.w("OneSignalExample", "notificationReceived!!!!!!");
   DebuggingHelper.printObject(notification);
   DebuggingHelper.printObject(notification.payload);
   }
   }
   ```
4. And this is your **ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler**:

   ```
      public class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler {

       @Override
       public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult openedResult) {
   OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType =    openedResult.action.actionType;
   JSONObject data = openedResult.notification.payload.additionalData;

   String customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
     if (data != null) {
       customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
       if (customKey != null)
           Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " +     customKey);
   }
   if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
       Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + openedResult.action.actionID);

   // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.
   /*
    * Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), YourActivity.class);
    * intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
    * Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);
    */
   // Follow the instructions in the link below to prevent the launcher
   // Activity from starting.
   // https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-customizations#changing-the-open-action-of-a-notification
     }
     }
   ```

   I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Tips on logging OneSignal notifications using Logback for Android:

- see Iman's answer above and this link:  https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/app/src/main/java/com/onesignal/example/OneSignalExampleApp.java
- I was not able to log any OneSignal events w/ in the handlers when Logback for Android was configured for ASYNC

Use this or similar logback.xml

```
    <configuration debug="true">

  <!-- Create a tab delimited file appender for a log in the application's data directory -->
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DATA_DIR}/logs/${PACKAGE_NAME}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>${DATA_DIR}/logs/${PACKAGE_NAME}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <minIndex>1</minIndex>
      <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>100KB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{yy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}:\t[%thread]:\t%level:\t%logger: \t%msg%n</pattern>
      <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>

    </encoder>
  </appender>


<!--
  <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </appender>
-->



  <!-- Create a logcat appender -->
  <appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS yy.MM.dd}\t[%thread]\t%-5level\t%logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
  </root>

<!--
<root level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
</root>
-->

</configuration>
```

- Here's my code:

> 

```
package org.MyAwesomeApp.onesignalTest.app;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import com.onesignal.*;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler;
import org.slf4j.*;
public class pkApplication extends Application {
//https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/
/*
static private final Provider SpongyCastleProvider = new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
static { java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(SpongyCastleProvider, 1); }
*/
static private final Logger mLog    = LoggerFactory.getLogger( pkApplication.class );
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //mLog.debug("pkApplication.OnCreate:\t name: " + SpongyCastleProvider.getName() + "\t info: " + SpongyCastleProvider.getInfo());
    initOneSignal();
}
void initOneSignal(){
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().build() );
/*
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
*/
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
//           .autoPromptLocation(true)
//           .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
             .setNotificationOpenedHandler( new pkNotificationOpenedHandler() )
             .setNotificationReceivedHandler( new pkNotificationReceivedHandler() )
             .init();
    OneSignal.sendTag("test1", "test1JD");
}//initOneSignal
// This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is runnning.
private class pkNotificationOpenedHandler implements NotificationOpenedHandler{
    @Override public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult openedResult ){
        OSNotification notification = openedResult.notification;
        mLog.debug( "notification Opened:\t" + notification.toJSONObject()  );
    }//n        otificationOpened
}//pkNotificationOpenedHandler
private class pkNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler{
    @Override public void notificationReceived( OSNotification notification ){
        mLog.debug( "notification received:\t" + notification.toJSONObject()  );
    }
}//pkNotificationReceivedHandler
}//pkApplication
```